# Entity framework support in .net core 2.1

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I have created a new application, using the SPA templare of `.netcore`, to this solution i want to add another project to handle the database connection(DAL). 
When i am adding `ASP.net core Web Application` to this solution, i then want to add to id an `ADO.net` entityframework template, but in the data section, it dont appear: 
[image]

So I end-up adding a `class Library(.net framework)`
and to it i can add an `ADO.net Entity Data Model`
[image]

So now in the solution, i have 2 projects, 1 is `.net core 2.1` for the API's, models and views(by angular).

The second project is a `.net framework 4.6.1, class library` project.
My question is, is it suppose to be like that?
is it a good thing to mix different frameworks

Comment: You should use EntityFramework Core instead. EF6 doesn't run on .NET Core (though there are plans to make it run on .NET Core 3.0), that means you can only run it when targeting .NET Framework >=4.5.1 / 4.6.1 or higher (depending on which ASP.NET Core version you want to run). You'd have to target .NET Framework with your ASP.NET Core project too in order it to work

Comment: You should only use EF6 if there is a feature which you absolutely need which isn't available in EF Core 2.1. Targeting net461 of course means, you can't run it on linux or mac (except on mono)

Comment: so what project should i add to the solution, in order for it to support `ef core`, when i am adding new project (Class Library, the supports .net core) i dont see any `ef core` template which i can add to it

Comment: There are no EF Core templates. You just create a .NET Standard Library project and add a Nuget Package, that's it. There are no UI tools for, emdx files and tools anymore. Just "Code first" and scaffold (db first) modes

Comment: @Tseng it was super easy to make that with a template.. why did they drop this :/

Comment: Too much trouble keeping that in sync when database or code changes are required. It was the least popular of the three modes. Have a read on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890367.aspx (EF Core is there still referred as EF7 btw, its rather old)

Comment: EDMX was frankly garbage, and was round-filed accordingly. If you still want a more GUI approach to creating your models, you can simply use something like SSMS to design your database tables, and then just scaffold your existing database in your project using EF Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

Answer (score 0):

Please see this article regarding what each framework is, and what each is specifically designed for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

In a nutshell, your requirements drive which framework you choose.

I would recommend sticking with EF Core (just my personal opinion, take it or leave it) The EF Core method of database first is only recommended if you require a 1 time migration from a source database. [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db)

If you need to CONTINUE working with an entity model past the first migration, it would be in your best interest to use Entity Framework 6, on a .NET Framework library like you have.  But that doesn't stop you from using EF Core as your OR/M, because you can indeed have .NET Core reference .NET Framework.